# Ubuntu 17.10 in VirtualBox: "A start job is running for Hold"

Tags: boot, virtualbox, 17.10

I had Ubuntu 17.04 (no longer supported) in VirtualBox. After upgrading the VB guest additions to 5.2.6 from 5.2.4 it would only boot to a black screen.

I decided to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch. I installed 17.10.  After installing the VB guest additions, the boot process hangs with the message

> A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (23s / no limit)

The system would only boot if I disable 3D acceleration for VirtualBox. But if I do that, the Ubuntu desktop is very slow.

Is there any way to get 17.10 running in VirtualBox 5.2.6 with good performance, like I could run 17.04?

The host is macOS 10.13.3, NVIDIA 750M graphics

Comment: Maybe I should just go back to 16.04 ...

Comment: It might be a good idea. Or try to use Xorg instead of Wayland.

Comment: @dadexix86 I think I found the problem. The VB website says that [the 5.2.6 guest additions are broken](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).  Unfortunately, I found this only after deleting 17.10.  But I'll probably be better off with 16.04 anyway.

Comment: I didn't know it, sorry! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because the 5.2.6 VirtualBox guest additions are broken, as mentioned on [the VirtualBox website](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads):

> Important: The Guest Additions which come with VirtualBox 5.2.6 and 5.1.32 do not work properly on Linux guests with 3D enabled. Here are updated versions for [5.2.6](https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.2.7-120528.iso) and [5.1.32](https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.1.33-120529.iso).

Answer (score 2):

I resolved by following steps in VirtualBox-5.2.18:

1. Unchecked 3D acceleration option in Setting | Display of your machine.
2. Start your machine
3. Add "Guest Additions" in top menu "device" of the window.
4. Shutdown
5. Checked 3D acceleration option in Setting | Display of your machine.
6. Start your machine again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was related to the wrong version of guest modules. I solved it using:

`sudo rcvboxadd setup`

It may also require to install dev packages before `sudo apt install gcc make perl`

Answer (score 0):

For older VBox versions follow up @Szabolcs Answer.
@Alexey Prokhorov answer is a good go for troubleshooting newer versions as you will get the failure reason output by running the rcvboxadd setup.

In my case VBoxLinuxAdditions did not install properly because of missing kernel headers and that triggered this start job failure. I solved this by installing the proper kernel headers.

Prompt output I got was:

> VirtualBox Guest Additions: Kernel headers not found for target kernel
> <kernel_version>. Please install them and execute
> /sbin/rcvboxadd setup

Kernel headers for Ubuntu :

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

After that run the setup:

```
sudo rcvboxadd setup
```

Just reboot and you should be ok.